# Explain of JSON format in google charts

Tags: php, json, charts

I made a google bar chart with json data.
But i do not understand wht the "c" and "v" do.

Would be very happy, if someone could give me a short explaination for what they are and why I have to use them.

```
<?php
//Balkendiagramm
$query_barchart = "SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN name_Gleitzeitrahmen = 'Ja' THEN 1 END) as Ja,COUNT(CASE WHEN name_Gleitzeitrahmen = 'Nein' THEN 1 END)as Nein,quarter(datum) as quartal FROM landrat_dashboard GROUP BY quartal";
$result_barchart = mysqli_query($con,$query_barchart);

$rows_barchart = array();
$table_barchart = array();
$table_barchart['cols'] = array(

// Hier werden die Namen für die Spalten festgelegt
// Eine Spalte muss vom Typ String sein, sie repräsentiert den Spalten Titel, 
// die anderen sind vom Typ number, da google-chart Zahlen braucht, um Prozentangaben oder andere Formate untereinander zu vergleichen
array('label' => 'Quartal', 'type' => 'string'),
array('label' => 'Anzahl Ja', 'type' => 'number'),
array('label' => 'Anzahl Nein', 'type' => 'number')
);

$rows_barchart = array();
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_barchart)) {
    $temp = array();
    // Folgende Zeile wird benötigt, um das Diagramm in Teilstücke aufzuteilen. Quasi die erste Zeile einer Tabelle
    $temp[] = array('v' => (string) $r['quartal']); 

    // Hier werden Werte für jedes Teistück vergeben. Quasi die Zeilen einer Tabelle
    $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $r['Ja'] ); 
    $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $r['Nein'] );
    $rows_barchart[] = array('c' => $temp); 
}

$table_barchart['rows'] = $rows_barchart;
$jsonTable_barchart = json_encode($table_barchart);// Das Array wird in JSON Format umgewandelt, welches vom google-chart akzeptiert wird.
//echo $jsonTable_barchart;
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Cell**  = c

**Value** = v (used for both for cell value and the value value)

You can create your data in 2 ways, using the API methods or building from a literal string (json) like your doing. The later requires the `c` and `v` object properties, because you could order them differently and it would still work.

**From the manual:** 
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataTable

Using an json object example.

```
var dt = new google.visualization.DataTable({
    cols: [{id: 'task', label: 'Task', type: 'string'},
           {id: 'hours', label: 'Hours per Day', type: 'number'}],
    rows: [{c:[{v: 'Work'}, {v: 11}]},
           {c:[{v: 'Eat'}, {v: 2}]},
           {c:[{v: 'Commute'}, {v: 2}]},
           {c:[{v: 'Watch TV'}, {v:2}]},
           {c:[{v: 'Sleep'}, {v:7, f:'7.000'}]}]
    }, 0.6);
```

Using the API methods.

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'Task');
data.addColumn('number', 'Hours per Day');
data.addRows([
  ['Work', 11],
  ['Eat', 2],
  ['Commute', 2],
  ['Watch TV', 2],
  ['Sleep', {v:7, f:'7.000'}]
]);
```

**Columns and cells**

`cols` Example

```
cols: [{id: 'A', label: 'NEW A', type: 'string'},
       {id: 'B', label: 'B-label', type: 'number'},
       {id: 'C', label: 'C-label', type: 'date'}]
```

`rows` Property

The rows property holds an array of row objects.

Each row object has one required property called `c`, which is an array of cells in that row. It also has an optional `p` property that defines a map of arbitrary custom values to assign to the whole row. If your visualization supports any row-level properties it will describe them; otherwise, this property will be ignored.

**Cell Objects**

Each cell in the table is described by an object with the following properties:

`v` [Optional] The cell value. The data type should match the column data type. If the cell is null, the `v` property should be null, though it can still have `f` and `p` properties.

All can be found in the docs link above.